# Finding the Eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the matrix given below:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$

The eigenvalues for this matrix are

$\dfrac{1+\sqrt 5}{2},\dfrac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}.$

I am facing trouble finding the eigenvectors. Please help.

Comment: Use the definition. For example, you want to solve the system $$A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},$$ where $\lambda=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}
    x+y  \\
    x 
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    (\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}).x  \\
    (\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}).y
  \end{bmatrix}$

This is where I am facing trouble.

Comment: So just equate the components and solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is an eigenvector then $(cx,cy)$ is too; so set $y=1$ and then solve to get a particular eigenvector, and the others are multiples of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find eigenvalues from the characteristic polynomial

$\lambda^2-\lambda-1=(\lambda+(\sqrt(5)-1)/2)*(\lambda-(\sqrt(5)+1)/2)$

$\lambda_1=(-\sqrt(5)+1)/2$

$\lambda_2=(\sqrt(5)+1)/2$

---

For every λ we find its own vector(s):

$\lambda_1=(-\sqrt(5)+1)/2$

$A-\lambda_1I=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} & 1 \\
1 & \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
\end{matrix}\right)$

$Av=\lambda v$ [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenvalues_and_the_characteristic_polynomial)

$ \Rightarrow (A-\lambda I)v=0$

So we have a homogeneous system of linear equations, we solve it by Gaussian Elimination: [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems)

$\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\
1 & \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$

$\begin{matrix}
x_1 & +\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}*x_2 & = & 0
\end{matrix}$

General Solution: $X=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2}*x_2 \\
x_2
\end{matrix}\right)$

Let $x_2=1, v_1=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$

---

$\lambda_2=(\sqrt(5)+1)/2$

$A-\lambda_2I=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2} & 1 \\
1 & \frac{-\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
\end{matrix}\right)$

$(A-\lambda I)v=0$ [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenvalues_and_the_characteristic_polynomial)

So we have a homogeneous system of linear equations, we solve it by Gaussian Elimination: [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems)

$\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\
1 & \frac{-\sqrt{5}-1}{2} & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$

$\begin{matrix}
x_1 & -\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}*x_2 & = & 0
\end{matrix}$

General Solution: $X=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}*x_2 \\
x_2
\end{matrix}\right)$

Let $x_2=1, v_2=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$

Answer (score 4):

You have an eigenvalue $\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2$.

An eigenvector will satisfy $A\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}=\phi\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}$; i.e., $\begin{bmatrix}x+y\\x\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\phi x \\ \phi y \end{bmatrix}.$

Solutions of this will be multiples of each other.

We could take $y=1$.  Then $x=\phi y=\phi$.  So an eigenvector is $\begin{bmatrix}\phi  \\  1 \end{bmatrix}.$

All the eigenvectors for this eigenvalue are given by $\begin{bmatrix}c\phi  \\  c\end{bmatrix}.$

Approach for the other eigenvalue is similar.